# Verifying AJAX if user logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, spring-security

I have Spring MVC application with spring security.
Users have to first log in to the system.
Based on their roles I want to give them access to specific AJAX Links?
How can I manage securing the AJAX Links from unauthenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

When user login to your system generate a random token in user table. Return this token in login success response.When you destroy the login session, or when user logout from the system simply remove the token from user table.

Now in each AJAX request send this token to the controller and verify if user is Authenticated or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: apart from token , is there any other method to secure AJAX links ?

Comment: You can create a middleware to verify id user is Authenticated or not. In your route file you can add that middleware to all the routes that AJAX using. This is another way.